# Tratar CustomError ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

Bom dia,

Estava tendo erro ao publicar o site de erros em runtime,

Criei uma página em branco ASPX e adicionei a tag no web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/internalerror.aspx" ></customErrors>
```

Porém, me retorna

> Runtime Error
>   Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

O que necessita para que consiga exibir o erro gerado?

Comment: Veja se você consegue identificar melhor o erro, olhando pelos eventos de aplicação no EventViewer.

Comment: Então, esse erro gera direto pelo servidor ao qual está hospedado, tem como ver mesmo assim? No ambiente de teste (IIS Express local) não gera erro...

Comment: Sim, você pode simular o erro e verificar diretamente no servidor hospedado.

Comment: Ta, como faço isso.

Comment: Simule o erro na sua aplicação, no momento que ocorrer o problema, vá ao servidor onde está hospedado, abra o visualizador de eventos do windows -> Logs do Windows -> Aplicativo. Procure na lista a direita, se há algum evento de erro referente ao seu site.

Comment: Me tire uma duvida, estava desenvolvendo na estrutura 4.6.1 porém o servidor ia até a 4.5.2, realizei o downgrade tudo certinho, porém algumas bibliotecas baixadas pelo NuGET aparecem a mensagem que foram compiladas na 4.6.1, será que seria esse o problema? porque em no IIS Express não apresenta erro (simulei um erro para ver se iria cair na página de erro e caiu normalmente)

Comment: Poderia ser... tenta publicar o site com a opção "Precompile during publishing" pra ver se não ocorre nenhum erro.

Comment: O Erro foi esse: O domínio do aplicativo em que o thread estava sendo executado foi

Comment: La no seu "customErrors" tenta adicionar essa tag: redirectMode="ResponseRedirect". E faz um teste novamente.

Comment: Exibiu o mesmo erro **Description:** An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

Comment: A sua página de erro esta completamente em branco? ou tenta alguma chamada do tipo Response.Redirect dentro dela?

Comment: Na Index.aspx e nem outra exite o Response.Redirect, o unico redirecionamento é pelo authentication que redireciona para login

Comment: Se eu retiro o customErros, é retornada Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Comment: Tira o customErrors e abre o site por dentro do servidor que ele está hospedado, lá você deverá conseguir ver o erro.

Comment: o que retorna é isso Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off". e apenas, um exemplo de como implementar custonError

Comment: Não, isso aparece pois você está acessando o site de outra máquina de onde está hospedado o site... Faça isso dentro do servidor.

Comment: Alterei o customerros para mode="off" o retorno foi esse
System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.

Uma exceção não tratada foi gerada durante a execução da solicitação da web atual. Informações sobre a origem e o local da exceção podem ser identificadas usando o rastreamento da pilha de exceções abaixo.

Comment: Bom agora temos outro cenário... Esse seu site já funcionou publicado alguma vez? Ou ele nunca funcionou e você estava tentando colocar o customErrors pra identificar o problema?

Comment: Publiquei ele hoje, primeira vez

Comment: Seria problema de incompatibilidade de estrutura? usar pacotes NuGET 4.6.1 e o servidor ser 4.5.2?

Comment: Sugiro então que você feche esse tópico e abra um relacionando sua dúvida com o System.Security.SecurityException... Faça uma breve pesquisa, esse problema não tem relação com target framework.

Comment: Com faz para encerrar?

Comment: Boa pergunta kkk

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/423967/erro-asp-net-securityexception-request-failed criei